# LDD and LDCONFIG => Strange problem Library not found although existant

Tags: linux

when I want to run a program I get the following error:

```
static:/usr/local/delegate# ./linux64-dg
./linux64-dg: error while loading shared libraries: libpam.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Then I check if the lib is existent and it is!!

```
static:/usr/local/delegate# ldconfig -p | grep libpam.so.0
        libpam.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/libpam.so.0
```

But then ldd shows it could not be loaded:

```
   static:/usr/local/delegate# ldd linux64-dg
            linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7eec000)
            libnsl.so.1 => /lib32/libnsl.so.1 (0xf7ecb000)
            libdl.so.2 => /lib32/libdl.so.2 (0xf7ec7000)
            libutil.so.1 => /lib32/libutil.so.1 (0xf7ec3000)
            libpam.so.0 => not found
            libpthread.so.0 => /lib32/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7eab000)
            libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf7d59000)
            /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7eed000)
```

What could I do to solve this problem?

(Running `ldconfig` did not help.)

Thank you very much 
Jan

Comment: Could you provide the output of "uname -a" and "file /usr/local/delegate/linux64-dg"? The lib32 part seems not right.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. This was a binary distribution, I now downloaded the source and compiled it myself and everything is working now. (It seems I can't delete questions myself?)

Comment: file == /usr/local/delegate/linux64-dg: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, not stripped

## uname -a ==

Linux static 2.6.26-1-amd64 #1 SMP Sat Jan 10 17:57:00 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: hello touchstone, ohh now I also realilze what the problem is(32vs64 libs). Thank you very much!! You could copy your comment into an answer, then I will give you the tick for the solution. thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, great it's working now. I think the naming conventions for delegate are somewhat confusing, as seen here: http://www.delegate.org/mail-lists/delegate-en/3993

I guess everyone expects "something64" to be 64bit architecture and not "large file capabilities".